# Apache Commons Configuration: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, transitive-dependency, apache-commons-config

My POM contained:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Both sample codes from [Quick start guide, Reading a properties file](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/quick_start.html):

```java
Configurations configs = new Configurations();
try
{
    Configuration config = configs.properties(new File("config.properties"));
    // access configuration properties
    ...
}
catch (ConfigurationException cex)
{
    // Something went wrong
}
```

and [Properties files, Using PropertiesConfiguration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Properties_files):

```java
Parameters params = new Parameters();
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder =
    new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
    .configure(params.properties()
        .setFileName("usergui.properties"));
try
{
    Configuration config = builder.getConfiguration();
    ...
}
catch(ConfigurationException cex)
{
    // loading of the configuration file failed
}
```

throwed:

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean
...
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.createParametersProxy(Parameters.java:307)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.fileBased(Parameters.java:186)
at properties.PropertiesTest.testLoadAndStoreWithCommonsConfiguration(PropertiesTest.java:52)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean
```

`mvn dependency:tree` showed:

```java
...
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
...
```

[`commons-configuration2`'s POM](https://search.maven.org/classic/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/commons/commons-configuration2/2.3/commons-configuration2-2.3.pom) contains:

```java
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
        <optional>true</optional><
    /dependency>
    ...
```

Comment: The dependency is in the POM since at least 2011, but declared as "optional". I suppose it's the reason why gradle does not include it per default. The reason for  optional is not clear: https://github.com/apache/commons-configuration/commit/3074a153514c28f853e181f0667748fb22037119

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I added [the following dependency](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:commons-beanutils%20AND%20a:commons-beanutils&core=gav) to my POM and it worked:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

#### UPDATE

[The latest POM of `commons-configuration2`](https://github.com/apache/commons-configuration/blob/master/pom.xml) (as of Oct '21) declares `<version>1.9.4`. I didn't try that but it may work with later versions of Commons Configuration.

Comment: The dependency is in the POM since at least 2011, see my other comment under the question itself.

Answer (score -2):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding the code in `pom.xml`, I found that it doesn't work.

I downloaded the jar, put it into `lib` content under  `Web-INF`, then it works.

I think that Maven's plugin log causes it to die, it can not update or delete the jar automatically.

Comment: Putting dependencies into `lib` folders is old-school and definitely not the canonical Maven way. Which Maven plugin are you referring to?